# Wordpress theme appearing issue with internet explorer

Tags: wordpress-theming, internet-explorer-11

I am facing problem with my workplace internet explorer browser v11 only with websites that use wordpress
The theme is not apearing well
please take a look a sample screenshot
http://prnt.sc/d0q1nq

thank you